# getting an intial copy of redux state on render to reset it after a button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I've got some buttons in my navbar when clicked return a filtered state. These objects are then used to render cards in my UI.

```
  <div className="filter-buttons">
        <button className="filter-btn" onClick={() => setFilter("nature")}>Nature</button>
        <button className="filter-btn" onClick={() => setFilter("tech")}>Tech</button>
        <button className="filter-btn" onClick={() => setFilter("education")}>Education</button>
      </div>
```

I'm using redux toolkit library for my state. I pull in all blog objects and store it into a variable. I have a useEffect hook that runs everytime a button is clicked to try and reset the state and filter all the objects again.

```
const blogsCopy = JSON.stringify(useSelector((state) => state.blog));
  const allBlogs = useSelector((state) => state.blog);
  const myBlogs = useSelector((state) => state.user.blogs);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");
  const originalState = useMemo(() => JSON.parse(blogsCopy), []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setNavFilterLoading(true);
    let filteredBlogs = [];
    const keys = Object.keys(allBlogs);
    if (filter.startsWith("nat")) {
      // reset the state to the original state
      dispatch(setWholeState(originalState));
      console.log("original state", originalState);
      filteredBlogs = keys.filter(key => allBlogs[key].tags.some(tag => tag.startsWith("nat"))).map((key, index) => ({index, ...allBlogs[key]})
      );
    } else if (filter.startsWith("tech")) {
      filteredBlogs = keys.filter(key => allBlogs[key].tags.some(tag => tag.startsWith("tech"))).map((key, index) => ({index, ...allBlogs[key]})
      );
    } else if (filter.startsWith("edu")) {
      filteredBlogs = keys.filter(key => allBlogs[key].tags.some(tag => tag.startsWith("edu"))).map((key, index) => ({index, ...allBlogs[key]})
      );
    } else {
      filteredBlogs = keys.map((key, index) => ({index, ...allBlogs[key]})
      );
    }
    dispatch(setWholeState(filteredBlogs));
    setNavFilterLoading(false);
  }, [filter]);
```

Issue with this implementation is, the object gets mutated and I'm not able to reset the state again. If I clicked on the nature button, it will return 3 objects. If one of the three includes a 'tech' tag. It will filter the three objects and return one object.
I want it to reset the whole state to an initial copy to properly filter it out. Not filter what has been filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the use of `useEffect` to save `filteredBlogs` to the store might not be necessary here since `filter` seems to be for local use only.

Assuming that the goal is to filter data for conditional display, and the data retrieved from store works as expected, perhaps there is no need to mutate the data, instead a local `filteredBlogs` can be created within the component.

A rough example could be something like:

```
const blogsCopy = JSON.stringify(useSelector((state) => state.blog));
const allBlogs = useSelector((state) => state.blog);
const myBlogs = useSelector((state) => state.user.blogs);
const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");

const filteredBlogs = allBlogs.filter((item) =>
  filter ? item.tags.some((tag) => tag.startsWith(filter)) : true
);
```

Local `filteredBlogs` can then be used for output with `filteredBlogs.map()` and it would be updated when the `filter` state change.

Perhaps the buttons could also be changed to save the shorter value as `filter`, for simpler logic:

```
<div className="filter-buttons">
 <button className="filter-btn" onClick={() => setFilter("")}>Clear all</button>
 <button className="filter-btn" onClick={() => setFilter("nat")}>Nature</button>
 <button className="filter-btn" onClick={() => setFilter("tech")}>Tech</button>
 <button className="filter-btn" onClick={() => setFilter("edu")}>Education</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I've got other components relying on the data, the component I've shared is the navbar. Here's the repo for a better look at the implementation -- https://github.com/YasinAdan/simpleblogs

Comment: I'll share the data with different components by passing the filtered state to a higher component & checking if theres anything in it. If there is, rendering that if not, render all.

Comment: @mozart Not sure if it would work in the actual project, but any chances to save the `filter` value to the store instead? Perhaps other components can access `allBlogs` and `filter` for a filtered version if needed, with some quick calculation on the go, and the store can be lighter too.

Comment: I'll give that a shot as well, that would be a better implementation for sure.